# How many Functional Dependency in this relation?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I've been trying to find the FDs for this relation.

```
Relation X
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| P | Q | R | S | T | U |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| p | c | e | i | k | v |
| p | d | f | j | k | w |
| p | d | g | j | n | y |
| p | d | g | i | n | z |
| q | d | f | i | k | x |
| q | c | g | j | m | y |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This is a question in my assignment. Here are my "answer" but I just can't be sure.

```
S, U --> R  
P, R --> Q, T
P, U --> Q, R, S, T  
Q, U --> P, R, S, T  
T, U --> P, Q, R, S
```

Am I right or just ridiculously wrong?

Comment: What are your justifications, and which one(s) are you unsure of?

Comment: What I was trying here was to find any unique combination for LHS... And I wish I knew any better and more systematic method. So basically I'm unsure of everyone.

Comment: So you are just guessing, and asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: I knew someone would say this. All I can say is that that was never my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of task is not so easy to solve by hand, since one has to find **all the possible subsets of attributes**, to see if a certain subset has always a unique value for another attribute, or set of attributes. In this case, one should check 2<sup>6</sup> = 64 different combinations to find those that are compatible with the definition of functional dependency.

The most sensible thing is to use a program to find those combinations.

Here is the solution, automatically generated:

```
U → R S
P R → Q T
Q T → R
R T → Q
P U → Q T
Q R → T
R S → U
R S T → P
T U → P Q
Q U → P T
Q R S → P
Q S T → P U
P S T → Q R U
```

Of course you can reduce this set by finding a cover with a smaller number of dependencies, like the following one:

```
U → R S
P R → Q
Q T → R
Q R → T
R T → Q
R S → U
T U → P
P S T → Q
```

Comment: Thank you sir. What I wanted is the reasoning rather than the answer. So basically if I were doing this in exam, I would have had to test all 64 combinations, right?

Comment: In theory, yes. Maybe your teacher want just that you check with one or two attributes. This exercise is quite lengthy and not so interesting!

Comment: And may I ask. For P, U -> Q, R, S, T, why is this wrong?

Comment: @MichaelLau, U -> R S, already, while P U -> Q T, so it is correct that P U -> Q R S T. The program that I used find only the minimum number of dependencies.

Comment: It is not so much wrong as redundant, since U->RS, U is a subset of PU and RS is a subset of QRST.